# Systemverilog bit-shift difference between {<<{signal}} and {signal<<1}?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have the following piece of code which the Vivado simulator doesn't seem to support (results in ERROR: [XSIM 43-3209] - Unsupported Construct):

```
assign b = {<<{a}};
```

Wondering if I can just change this code to the following:

```
assign b = a<<1;
```

Could someone please confirm that the 2 lines above are identical? 
Note that both a and b are 8 bit wide. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not the same. `{<<{a}}` is a bit reversal.
Assuming `a` was declared with the range `[7:0]`, you would need to write

```
assign b = {a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7]};
```